# support of utf-8 when dealing with mysqldb

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-python

when I insert a query in mysql,
 I do the following:

`execute(query.encode('utf8'))`

I first make the string compatible to unicode and then execute.

Now when I am retrieving the data again from sql to my python code, do I need to make it unicode compatible again by applying encode function?
If yes, then sql returns block of rows, How do I encode all?

I get rows using `cursor.fetchall()`. how do i make each element of row as unicode compatible?

Answer (score 0):

step one: read and understand this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html #IMPORTANT

Now you know that all text data in your program should be unicode (and you are not
mistaking unicode data for an utf-8 encoded string, or "encode" with "decode" anymore)

You can specify the encoding to be used when creating your mysql connection - specify it there: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/ <-check for the "charset" parameter in the "**init**" method of the "connections" module - it can be passed as a parameter to the `MySQLdb.connect` call

From there on, all text data retrieved from this connection will be presented to Python as unicode, encoding the data stored on the database as unicode strings.